# How to make progress loading animation?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to make the animation progress to a certain number value. I get errors, I can't figure out what the reason is. SwiftUi IOS15

What are the parameters -
Number: 600;
Total: 1000

I am trying to run a progress animation to the number 600 out of 1000

```
let number: String
let total: Int
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

ProgressView(name, value: Double(number), total: Double(total))
  .onReceive(timer) { _ in
      if number < Double(total) {
         Double(number) += Double.random(in: 0...4)
         }
     }
```

UPD:
This is part of the code that I didn't add initially

```
struct Params: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let num: String
}

extension Params {
    static func getAll() -> [Params] {
        return [
            Params(num: "650"),
            Params(num: "80"),
            Params(num: "900")
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `number` property is a `String`, while `Double(total)` is a `Double`. You cannot compare a `String` and a `Double` with the `<` operator.

Your `number` property and your `total` property should both be declared `Double`, so you don't have to constantly convert them from `String` to `Double`.

Also, you cannot assign to a function call like `Double(number)`, so `Double(number) += ...` cannot work.

Also, you cannot assign to a property declared with `let` like `let number: String`.

Also, if you want to modify a property in an `onReceive` body, the property needs to be wrapped with `@State` or `@Binding`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct DemoView: View {
    var name: String
    var max: Double
    var total: Double
    @State var number: Double = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ProgressView(name, value: number, total: total)
                .onReceive(
                    Timer.publish(
                        every: 0.1,
                        on: .main,
                        in: .common
                    ).autoconnect()
                ) { _ in
                    if number < max {
                        number += Double.random(in: 0...4)
                    }
                }
            
            Button("Reset") { number = 0 }
        }
    }
}

import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(
    DemoView(
        name: "Test",
        max: 600,
        total: 1000
    ).padding()
)
```

Comment: I have updated my code, I get data from the `struct Params: Identifiable` structure, then I display them via ForEach, please take a look

Comment: I don't understand why that makes a difference. Convert the `String`s to `Double`s once when you initialize the view that wraps the `ProgressView`.

Comment: Then how do I pass the String value to `max:`

Comment: I can use it like this `max: Double(num)!` The `num` value is a String from the `struct Params: Identifiable` structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide full code for the file?
On the screenshot there are multiple mistakes:

1. You cannot compare `number` and `Double(total)`, because they are of different types.
   If you want to compare some number inside a `String`, firstly convert your string to a number, for example: `let intFromString = Int(number)`, then you will be able to compare like this: `if intFromString < total { ... }`
2. You cannot add Double to your String. You can add Double to another Double, and if this happens inside some View, you should use @State properties, for example:

- `@State var number: Double = 0`
- `@State var total: Int = 0`

And later: `number += Double.random...`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know that your option works, but it doesn't suit me, because I pass parameters to progressView from another structure

Comment: I added the code, it shows where I get the data from